# Display the data stored in a mysql database column as html list elements

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a form where the user inserts data inside mysql table and I display that data into another webpage of my website. Specifically,it's directions. I want the directions to display as an ordered html list.[image]
Example:

1) Do this.

2) Do this too.

Instead of: 1) Do this. 2) Do this too.

When the data is submited, I manually write html code inside so it appears the way I want. Which is something wrong, I think. Isn't there any other way to achieve this?[image: That's what I do]

This is the php code that interacts with the html form:

```
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table (something, something, something,  method) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $_POST['something'], $_POST['something'], $_POST['something'], $_POST['method']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    echo 'Congratulations!';
```

This is the php code that I use to display the content to the other web page.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT something, something, method FROM table WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows === 0) exit('Nothing exists here.');
    $stmt->bind_result($something, $something, $method);
    $stmt->fetch();
     echo "$method";
```

I want whatever is written inside Method textarea to appear as list,like the example above.
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean you manually write html code? Isn't this happening in a PHP script?

Comment: Add a `<br>` after the `</li>`

Comment: Or remove the CSS that is causing an ordered list to display like that

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, unless you're overriding the default CSS for list items.

Comment: What exact data are you outputting and how exactly are you outputting it?  It looks like you already know how to create an ordered list in HTML, so it's not really clear what the problem is.

Comment: I don't really see the connection between the two images.

Comment: The problem is that every time someone submits a method,I have to go inside the database at that specific row and add the <li> so it appears as an ordered list. I edited it,please take a look again. Thanks.

Comment: @F4-E: Maybe you're just looking for a rich text editor to use on your website?  There are many plugins and packages available for that.